# How to get file hash of OfficeActivity schema in Azure Sentinel?

Tags: azure, security, hash, office365, azure-sentinel

I have checked thoroughly for the answer for this question but haven't had much luck. It appears it isn't possible to get the file hash of any algorithm from OfficeActivity schema. Although, I am posting this question here to validate I haven't missed anything!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, file hashes are not part of the OfficeActivity table.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/officeactivity

However, if you have Defender for Endpoint, you could correlate the events from the DeviceFileEvents table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/reference/tables/devicefileevents

Likely a join would work on the
OfficeActivity / ClientMachineName, and DeviceFileEvents / DeviceName columns of the tables.